# What is the best way to store an NSString?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, serialization, nsstring, plist

I'm making an iOS app in Xcode 4 that needs to save one `NSString` variable. Does anyone know if using a .plist file is the best way to do this if so, what code do you need to store and retrive `NSString`s?

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Actually I introduced that error in the last line (oops)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best place would be to store it in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"My String" forKey:@"kMyStringKey"];
```

Then to call it:

```
lblMyLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kMyStringKey"];
```

Comment: Yep, I would do this. You beat me to the punch! :)

Comment: Thank you heaps!!! ill give that a go (sorry 4 da bad gramma ;)

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to store an `NSString` because needs vary. Plist in this case is more than necessary (based on the description).

**Option A** You could just use: `- [NSString writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:]`. in this case, you only need to remember the file URL and encoding you saved it in.

**Option B** another option would be to save it via `NSCoding` -- this allows `NSString` to choose the serialized representation it finds is best, given the string it represents.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't recommend `NSUserDefaults` here. Any info on that?

Comment: @RobertKarl two reasons: a) it's not specified in the OP that the value *belongs* in user defaults. therefore, i assume it does not belong there. b) using WrightCS's example; that is effectively a glorified/persistent global value. also not safe to assume that is compatible with the OP's needs because there can be only one value for that key. therefore, i don't recommend `NSUserDefaults` as the "best way" to store an arbitrary `NSString`. that the OP suggested a plist file also suggests that a file is more in line with the OP's usage. will dig up a link for point a…

Comment: @RobertKarl see Peter Hosey's well-worded explanation of when to use and when not to use `NSUserDefaults` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520797/when-not-to-abuse-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! I may need to edit my apps ;)